# Sending session data to React frontend using Larvel backend

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, typescript

I have a somewhat simple authentication system using ReactTS as a frontend and Laravel as a backend. What I am looking to do is send errors from the backend to the frontend when I redirect a user. This is the code I currently have:

```php
return redirect('/account')->withErrors('Error here');
```

I have also tried:

```php
return redirect('/account')->with('message', 'Error here');
```

But in my React frontend I use a flash manager to handle errors. However I do not know how to get this error or session data in the frontend. Code:

```
addFlash({ key: 'account', message: 'error here' });
```

This function just takes a message and shows it to the user with a coloured bar. My issue is I do not know how to get these errors I am redirecting with in the frontend.

Comment: You'd have to use `session('message')` in a php script (this refers to the `session()` helper function from Laravel) and pass it to your javascript

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you have separated backend and frontend and probably have an API that handles your requests. If this is the case and I understood it correctly then I'll tell you how I handled it and maybe it will help you as well.

In my case, I'm returning an HTTP response no matter if it is for errors or for success and I think that you should do the same, let me show you a simple example to explain it better for you.

Here's my controller (simplified for your concern):

```
class CreateEventRegistrationController
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        /** 
          Here you validate your fields or something
          specific logic for your project.
        */
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'firstName'    => 'required',
            'lastName'     => 'required'
        ]);

        /**
          If your validation fails then throw an HttpResponseException
        */

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
                'errors' => $validator->errors()
            ]));
        }

       /** 
         Store something in database or whatever you need to do in your app
       */

        

        /**
          And at last return a successful response
          after everything is working as expected.
        */
        return response('Created successfully', Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

And with this logic then I have the messages on my frontend part where I handle there the error messages or success ones.

Hope this helps you, if I couldn't understand your issue properly you can comment it more specifically so I can help you more.

Comment: I should have specified my question better. So essentially what I am making is an OAuth system. And the callback url is part of the backend. What I want to do is if there is an error... redirect the user to the frontend and render an error there, Normally what I would do is catch errors from http requests to the api. But in this case there is nothing to catch, I simply need to redirect the user to the frontend with a code that is somehow readable by the React frontend.